# Proving a piecewise function is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I am dealing with the following function:
$f=
\begin{cases}
0\text{  if  }x<0\\
1\text{  if  }x\geq 0\\
\end{cases}
$
I am trying to prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[-1,1]$, and that $\int_{-1}^1f=1$.  This is what I have so far:

Let $\varepsilon >0$, and let $P$ be a tagged partition of mesh $<\delta$. Let $L=\int_{-1}^1f=1$.  Let $t_i$ be the tags.  If $t_i<0$, then $f(t_i)=0$.  If $t_i\geq 0$, then $f(t_i)=1$.  Assume that $t_i<0$ up to $i=k+1$, and $t_i\geq0$ for all $i$ up to $k$. Then $S(f;P)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}f(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})+\sum_{i=k+1}^nf(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})=0+1(x_n-x_k)=1-x_k$.  Then $|L-S(f;P)|=|x_k|$.

This is where I'm stuck now. How can I show that $|x_k|<\delta$?

Comment: Just a few superficial comments on the writing. I think you need to fix the part where you wrote "$t_i < 0$ up to $i = k + 1$ and $t_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ up to $k$." Also, when you write your final version, you'll want to define $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$, and write $L = 1$ without mentioning the integral, since the point is to prove its existence. The upper limit in the first sum should probably be $k$ instead of $k + 1$ (depending on how you fix the part about the $t_i$'s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $x_{k-1} \leq t_k < 0 \leq t_{k+1} \leq x_{k+1}$, $x_k \in (x_{k-1},x_{k+1})$, and $x_{k+1} - x_{k - 1} < 2\delta$, so $|x_k| < 2\delta$.

I would probably have defined $k$ in terms of where the $x_i$'s change sign rather than where the $t_i$'s do, but your method works too.